# Use external fonts in Wordpress stylesheet

Tags: theme-development

I'm having a go at designing a premium WP theme, and I've found numerous plugins that allow you to load fonts from Google Web Fonts and other services. However, how do I let administrators actually configure the site-wide heading and body text fonts?

**To clarify:** When writing a stylesheet, I need to type in the name of the fonts that will be used (e.g. `h1 { font-family: Cuprum }`. However, I want to be able to choose different fonts *for my CSS* from my admin panel by picking from available Google Web Fonts.

One option I can think of is using `font-family: HeaderFont`, `font-family: BodyFont`, etc. in my CSS, and then loading whichever fonts have been chosen under those names using `@font-face`, e.g.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HeaderText';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cuprum'), local('Cuprum-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v3/sp1_LTSOMWWV0K5VTuZzvQ.woff) format('woff');
}
```

But that seems like quite a complex solution, and I haven't seen it done that way. What's the accepted way to do this?

Comment: Are you addressing the application of ANY font or is there a particular difficulty when it comes to applying external fonts?

Comment: @kalengi - please see my edit; I'm finding it quite complex to describe what I need, although it's actually quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

1. Learn from another plugin
   Take a look at this plugins code to find out how it integrates Google Fonts http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-fonts/screenshots/
2. Learn by example create your own Theme Panel
   a. Here's a wp-tut http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

b. (from comments below) The easiest approach is to just output the user's CSS into the page template ... That's also the nasty approach. The best method will be to write the users saved options to a custom.css file and even save them in the Wordpress database.

1. Develop your theme using a theme framework
   WooThemes or Thesis are probably great starting points
   see also:
   http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/10/a-comparison-of-leading-wordpress-theme-frameworks/

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I want to achieve; however, it seems like quite the inelegant solution - maybe there's an even better way?

Comment: There's a tut on wp-tuts that covers making your own admin page for your theme ... It's probably where I would start

Comment: Sure I will! That seems the lesser problem, though - how do I put the chosen fonts in my CSS?

Comment: The easiest approach is to just output the CSS into the page template ... That's also the nasty approach.  The best method will be to write the users saved options to a custom.css file and even save them in the Wordpress database. Have you downloaded any of the free themes from woothemes ? That will probably help you alot

Comment: @Damien's approach is what I'd also go with. **Thesis**, a premium theme, has an options panel in admin that allows you to pick fonts for various sections of the page. Once you save, the selections are output to a file **layout.css**.

Comment: Hmm. I see. And the woothemes framework does it in the same manner, too. I guess I should cook up something myself! :)

Comment: @egasimus actually you read my mind ... i was thinking you can adapt someoneelses' theme framework for your purposes. Check this out: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/10/a-comparison-of-leading-wordpress-theme-frameworks/ and stay in touch, id love to know how you get on.